# mongo_mapper query returns no results, direct query in DB returns results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongomapper

Here is the setup:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongo_mapper', '>= 0.13.0.beta1'
gem 'plucky', '>= 0.6.5'
```

Controller:

```
@job = Job.where(:admin_id => a.id)
```

Rails console output (logger):

```
@job is []
```

One "a.id" value happens to be:

```
a.id is 51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1
```

Mongo Query directly:

```
db.jobs.find({ admin_id: "51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1" })

>>>Lots of stuff<<<
```

How many?

```
> db.jobs.find({ admin_id: "51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1" }).count()
202
```

So - why does this query return results when done direct in Mongo and return an empty array when called from the controller?

More specifically - here is the simple loop:

```
@tech_d = []
    @tech.each do |a|
      Rails.logger.info("a.id is " + a.id)
      @job = Job.where(:admin_id => a.id)
      Rails.logger.info("@job is " + @job.to_a.to_s)
```

Which yields stuff like this:

```
a.id is 51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1
@job is []
a.id is 51f976f2811d830002000adc
@job is []
```

But as I've already proven - there are results to this simple query when done direct in Mongo.

**EDIT - I've tried the GA version of mongo_mapper gem 0.12.0 and the results are the same (downgraded plucky to 0.5.2 to match - no change)

Answer (score 0):

You got no result because as you use it it would only create the query.

You will need to 'execute' it by appending `.all`

```
@job = Job.where(:admin_id => a.id)
```

will return you:

```
=> #<Plucky::Query admin_id: "51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1", transformer: #<Proc:0x00000003d5c2a0@/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:76 (lambda)>>
```

You should do:

```
@job = Job.where(:admin_id => a.id).all

or simply

@job = Job.all(:admin_id => a.id)
```

See next paragraph from here: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#criteria :

> Mongo has rich support for dynamic queries. MongoMapper uses Plucky to
>   construct query proxy objects that only retrieve data from Mongo when
>   needed. This allows a query to be composed of several conditions
>   before being evaluated.

Comment: Nope - sorry - this isn't the answer.  I've tried Job.where(query), Job.all(query), Job.where({query}), Job.all({query}), even went nuts with Job.find (which of course isn't a mongo_mapper function).  I've been working with Mongo and Plucky for some time now, and I perform many many queries like this one inside my application.  Something strange about this one in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Shoot me in the face, the answer turned out to be stringifying it...

a.id.to_s instead of a.id in the query.

That's so whack.  I can Rails.logger.info(a.id) and get output that's right - WITHOUT the to_s method - but I have to to_s it into the query...

Jesus that's so obvious it hurts me.

Comment: Logging implicitly calls to_s on the data passed to it. It looks like the issue is that you're storing string IDs in your DB rather than BSON IDs - this is generally recommended against.

Comment: Chris - I appreciate the comment, in my experience Logging statements do NOT implicitly call to_s on the data.  Many, many, many times I refresh a page only to see "no implicit conversion of X to string" and I always have to go back and add to_s on the var.  This happens with Date objects, Time objects, Mongo plucky queries, JSON, any Integer / Array. Literally everything requires that I manually add to_s to get it to display in the logger.  Please teach me how to tell Logger to implicitly add to_s - it would help me a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I believe it's calling `#inspect` rather than `#to_s`. See https://gist.github.com/cheald/dd95008667ff5992fb44 - I believe the issue stands that you have string IDs in the DB rather than BSON IDs; they are separate types and are treated as such.